# XSLT node value comparision

Tags: xslt

How Can I compare ip address with reference of family and name. using XSLT file. In Details, I have one xml file which has list of operatorstation nodes with each operator station has its unique information. So By considering first operatorstation node as a master comparing all remaining slave operatorStation information. First need to compare IPAddress by grouping Family & Name which gives result like shown below. So I am looking for starnsform script XSLT which give me result shown below.
  Please check xml file I am using as input, xml file as I am expecting output result and XSLT file I am working on it.
**Please ask question if anyone still not understand....**
Input xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<OperatorStationCollection xmlns="http://ACORD.org/Standards/Life/2">
  <OperatorStation><Name>OS01</Name>
    <Nodes>
      <DataNodeBase >
                <Family>NetworkSettings</Family>
                <Name>Internet</Name>
                <IPAddress>111.22.22.3</IPAddress>  
      </DataNodeBase>
    </Nodes>
  </OperatorStation>
  <OperatorStation><Name>OS02</Name>
    <Nodes>
          <DataNodeBase>
                <Family>NetworkSettings</Family>
                <Name>Internet</Name>
                <IPAddress>111.22.22.3</IPAddress>  
          </DataNodeBase>
    </Nodes>
  </OperatorStation>
  <OperatorStation><Name>OS03</Name>
    <Nodes>
          <DataNodeBase>
                <Family>NetworkSettings</Family>
                <Name>Internet</Name>
                <IPAddress>111.22.22.4</IPAddress>  
          </DataNodeBase>
    </Nodes>
  </OperatorStation>
  <OperatorStation><Name>OS04</Name>
    <Nodes>
        <DataNodeBase>
                <Family>NetworkSettings</Family>
                <Name>Internet</Name>
                <IPAddress>111.22.22.4</IPAddress>  
        </DataNodeBase>
    </Nodes>
  </OperatorStation>
</OperatorStationCollection>
```

Expected OUTPUT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<OperatorStationCollection > 
  <Result > 
    <Family>NetworkSettings</Family> 
    <AdaptorName>Internet</AdaptorName> 
    <os01>111.22.22.3</os01> 
    <os02>Equal</os02> 
    <os03>UnEqual</os03> 
    <os04>UnEqual</os04> 
  </Result > 
</OperatorStationCollection>
```

Script I am trying to add:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:ns="http://ACORD.org/Standards/Life/2" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:key name="kOperatorStation" match="OperatorStation" use="concat(Family,'#',Name)"/>
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:for-each select="OperatorStation[generate-id() = generate-id(key('kOperatorStation',concat(Family,'#',Name))[1])]" >
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:variable name="group" select="key('kOperatorStation',concat(current()/Family,'#',current()/Name))" />
        <xsl:for-each select= "$group" >
          <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*[local-name() != 'IPAddress']" />            
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

c# code for transform:

```
XmlReader objXmlReader = XmlReader.Create(@"C:\XMLFile1.xml");
            /*Transform and add arguments*/
            XmlReader xsltTransformReader= XmlReader.Create(@"C:\XSLTFile1.xslt");
            XslCompiledTransform objXslTransform = new XslCompiledTransform();
            objXslTransform.Load(xsltTransformReader);

           XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        settings.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;

        /*Do transformation*/
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        using (XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(new StringWriter(output), settings))
            {
                objXslTransform.Transform(objXmlReader, xw);             
                string result = output.ToString();
            }
```

Comment: Would it be possible for you to show the XML you are expecting to be output, along with any XSLT that you have currently tried? Thanks!

Comment: Can you edit the question the question to include this XML, rather than add it as a comment. Also, don't forget to include any XSLT you have tried. If you are still stuck, have a look at http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html first, as that explains "Muenchian Grouping" very well. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Tim, I am trying to add script I am working on it but getting format exception and unable to add script and also unable to add image in it.Thanks! Could you suggest me another way..I am looking for this result...Which I will show in HTML in tabular format......<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<OperatorStationCollection > 
 <Result >
  <Family>NetworkSettings</Family>
  <AdaptorName>Internet</AdaptorName>
  <os01>111.22.22.3</os01>
  <os02>Equal</os02>
  <os03>UnEqual</os03>
  <os04>UnEqual</os04>  
 </Result >
</OperatorStationCollection>

Comment: Hi Tim, I am waiting for your reply......

Comment: This question is currently closed, because it was not clear what was being asked, I am afraid. It can be re-opened though. You should edit it to include any XSLT that you have currently tried (even if it doesn't work!). Also, it would help if you explained the logic required. You say you are expecting the result "in HTML tabular format", but the output you have shown is XML. If XML is required, can you explain where the **os01**, **os02** tags come from. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I have made changes in xml file can check, now I want output as mensioned using transform script XSLT.If you dont understand anything please ask.

Comment: If you really don't have any XSLT to show, that is fine, but please can you explain where **os01**, **os02**, **os03** and **os04** come from. Once you do that, this question can probably be re-opened, and an answer provided. Thank you!

Comment: I told you I have changed xml file, you can see OS01,02,03,04. I have wasted so much time for adding script but editor gives me error not allow me to add script.

Comment: Now can see script I have added, I was trying to add same script from morning but now its added.

Comment: I have voted to re-open the question. Once re-opened, I will be able to provide you with a solution!

Comment: @Tim, since he's still very unclear what he wants, I don't know how you can answer it, but since you say you have a solution I'll vote to reopen.

Comment: @AshishPayghan, you should say in the question what your code is doing wrong, or what exactly it's not doing that it should be and what output you are getting.  Be specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* I have finally understood this question.

The following stylesheet will group the `OperatorStation` elements by the `Family` and `Name` elements located inside `Nodes/DataNodeBase`. Note that there is another `Name` element that is a direct child of `OperatorStation` - this is potentially confusing.

For each group, the first `IPAddress` element is listed and the others are compared to it. The names of these result elements are taken from the values of the (top) `Name` element (just to add some more confusion...).

Pay special attention to the handling of the namespace declared in the source XML document.

**Styleheet:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ns="http://ACORD.org/Standards/Life/2"
exclude-result-prefixes="ns"> 
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="kOperatorStation" match="ns:OperatorStation" use="concat(.//ns:Family, '#', .//ns:DataNodeBase/ns:Name)"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
<OperatorStationCollection>
    <xsl:for-each select="ns:OperatorStationCollection/ns:OperatorStation[generate-id() = generate-id(key('kOperatorStation',concat(.//ns:Family, '#', .//ns:DataNodeBase/ns:Name))[1])]" >
    <Result>
        <Family><xsl:value-of select=".//ns:Family"/></Family>
        <AdaptorName><xsl:value-of select=".//ns:DataNodeBase/ns:Name"/></AdaptorName>

        <xsl:variable name="ip" select=".//ns:IPAddress" />

        <xsl:for-each select="key('kOperatorStation', concat(.//ns:Family, '#', .//ns:DataNodeBase/ns:Name))" >  
                <xsl:element name="{ns:Name}">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="position()=1">
                            <xsl:value-of select="$ip"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test=".//ns:IPAddress=$ip">
                            <xsl:text>Equal</xsl:text>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:text>UnEqual</xsl:text>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Result> 
    </xsl:for-each>
</OperatorStationCollection>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Source XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<OperatorStationCollection xmlns="http://ACORD.org/Standards/Life/2">
    <OperatorStation>
        <Name>OS01</Name>
        <Nodes>
            <DataNodeBase >
                    <Family>NetworkSettings</Family>
                    <Name>Internet</Name>
                    <IPAddress>111.22.22.3</IPAddress>  
            </DataNodeBase>
        </Nodes>
    </OperatorStation>  
    <OperatorStation>
        <Name>OS02</Name>
        <Nodes>
            <DataNodeBase>
                <Family>NetworkSettings</Family>
                <Name>Internet</Name>
                <IPAddress>111.22.22.3</IPAddress>  
            </DataNodeBase>
        </Nodes>
        </OperatorStation>      
        <OperatorStation>
        <Name>OS03</Name>
        <Nodes>
            <DataNodeBase>
                <Family>NetworkSettings</Family>
                <Name>Internet</Name>
                <IPAddress>111.22.22.4</IPAddress>  
            </DataNodeBase>
        </Nodes>
    </OperatorStation>      
    <OperatorStation>
        <Name>OS04</Name>
        <Nodes>
            <DataNodeBase>
                <Family>NetworkSettings</Family>
                <Name>Internet</Name>
                <IPAddress>111.22.22.4</IPAddress>  
            </DataNodeBase>
        </Nodes>
    </OperatorStation>
</OperatorStationCollection>
```

**Result:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<OperatorStationCollection>
  <Result>
    <Family>NetworkSettings</Family>
    <AdaptorName>Internet</AdaptorName>
    <OS01>111.22.22.3</OS01>
    <OS02>Equal</OS02>
    <OS03>UnEqual</OS03>
    <OS04>UnEqual</OS04>
  </Result>
</OperatorStationCollection>
```

Comment: Hi Michael,Yes, You understand my question but it gives result...<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><OperatorStationCollection />.... not that you suggested/showed. Di you checked your result?

Comment: @AshishPayghan The result in my answer was obtained by performing an actual transformation using the **exact** source and stylesheet specified. I suggest *you* check your own implementation, because utf-16 encoding is not likely to happen spontaneously.

Comment: Hi Michael, I am trying to get result through C# code and also xml nodepad but giving same result.Could you help me to get expected result? where I am doing wrong? ... Exe link: http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=7973

Comment: In xml notepad you can add xml file and transform script to get result. I have added my c# code in question. Waiting for ur reply....Thanks

Comment: @AshishPayghan I am not using Notepad (or Windows) so I am afraid I cannot help you there. Same with C# coding. If you like, you can test the XSL transformation on its own here: http://xslfiddle.net/ In your place, I would test what encoding do you get using a minimal XML input, say just `<root/>` and a similarly minimal stylesheet, say an identity transform. That should tell you whether the problem is with the input or with the process.

Comment: Hi Michael Thanks for your effort, I got solution. I have raised another question It would be great if you have answer of it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20901103/how-to-compare-two-xml-nodes-and-get-compared-result-using-xslt