# How to compare column value result and display status?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

The link below described how to compare but it compare number of occurrence with no of stations
[convert XSLT code from version 2.0 to 1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20917729/convert-xslt-code-from-version-2-0-to-1-0?noredirect=1#comment31421259_20917729)

```
<xsl:when test="count(key('networksAndIP', concat(w3:Name, '|', w3:IPAddress))) = $allStationsCount">Equal</xsl:when>
```

but actually I want to compare real value that are present in table and shows compared status.

Result will be compared result of value that are exist in column not no of occurrence of matching record that are exist in input file. I want to change above code line or replacement of above code line which compares and gives incorrect result more than one same matching record exist.

In short  **count(key('networksAndIP', concat(w3:Name, '|', w3:IPAddress)))** gives total no of occurrence it may be 10 or 5 depends on number of records but total stations are only 3 ($allStationsCount), so it will never shows correct result

Below codes are exactly same as link I have provided, but I have made some changes in input xml file.

Input XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <OperatorStationCollection xmlns="http://www.w3.org" >
    <OperatorStation xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <Name>OS001</Name>
        <Nodes>
          <DataNodeBase xsi:type="Adaptor">
            <Family>NetworkSettings</Family>
            <Name>Network A</Name>  
            <IPAddress>111.11.11.1</IPAddress>        
          </DataNodeBase>          
          </Nodes>   
      </OperatorStation>      
    <OperatorStation xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <Name>OS002</Name>
      <Nodes>
        <DataNodeBase xsi:type="Adaptor">
          <Family>NetworkSettings</Family>
          <Name>Network A</Name>
          <IPAddress>111.11.11.1</IPAddress>
        </DataNodeBase>        
      </Nodes>
    </OperatorStation>
      <OperatorStation xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <Name>OS003</Name>
        <Nodes>
          <DataNodeBase xsi:type="Adaptor">
            <Family>NetworkSettings</Family>
            <Name>Network A</Name>
            <IPAddress>111.11.11.1</IPAddress>
          </DataNodeBase>
          <DataNodeBase xsi:type="Adaptor">
            <Family>NetworkSettings</Family>
            <Name>Network A</Name>
            <IPAddress>111.11.11.1</IPAddress>
          </DataNodeBase>          
        </Nodes>
      </OperatorStation>
    </OperatorStationCollection>
```

XSLT code

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:w3="http://www.w3.org">
   <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:key name="networks" match="w3:DataNodeBase" use="w3:Name"/>
   <xsl:key name="networksAndIP" match="w3:DataNodeBase" use="concat(w3:Name, '|', w3:IPAddress)"/>

   <xsl:variable name="allStations" select="//w3:OperatorStation"/>
   <xsl:variable name="allStationsCount" select="count($allStations)"/>

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <table><!-- Header row - two fixed columns plus one per station name -->
         <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Status</td>
            <xsl:for-each select="$allStations">
               <td>
                  <xsl:value-of select="w3:Name"/>
               </td>
            </xsl:for-each>
         </tr>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="//w3:DataNodeBase[generate-id() = generate-id(key('networks', w3:Name)[1])]"/>
      </table>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="w3:DataNodeBase">
      <tr>
         <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="w3:Name"/>
         </td>
         <td>
            <xsl:choose>
               <xsl:when test="count(key('networksAndIP', concat(w3:Name, '|', w3:IPAddress))) = $allStationsCount">Equal</xsl:when>
               <xsl:otherwise>Unequal</xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
         </td>
         <xsl:variable name="network" select="w3:Name"/>
         <xsl:for-each select="$allStations">
            <td>
               <xsl:value-of select="key('networks', $network)[../../w3:Name=current()/w3:Name]/w3:IPAddress"/>
            </td>
         </xsl:for-each>
      </tr>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output: Output shows status is Unequal even though all records are equal bcoz no of occurrence are many than no of stations.

```
   <table xmlns:w3="http://www.w3.org">
   <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Status</td>
      <td>OS001</td>
      <td>OS002</td>
      <td>OS003</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Network A</td>
      <td>Unequal</td>
      <td>111.11.11.1</td>
      <td>111.11.11.1</td>
      <td>111.11.11.1</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Expected output with same input file.

```
<table xmlns:w3="http://www.w3.org">
   <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Status</td>
      <td>OS001</td>
      <td>OS002</td>
      <td>OS003</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Network A</td>
      <td>Equal</td>
      <td>111.11.11.1</td>
      <td>111.11.11.1</td>
      <td>111.11.11.1</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Another Input example  file2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Base>
        <Directory>
          <InvokeBy>Registry</InvokeBy>          
          <SubDir>
            <FilePath>C:\Test\a.txt</FilePath>
            <Date>18.Apr.13</Date>    
          </SubDir>  
          <SubDir>
            <FilePath>C:\Test\b.txt</FilePath>
            <Date>18.Apr.13</Date>    
          </SubDir>
        </Directory>
        <Directory>
        <InvokeBy>Exe</InvokeBy>
          <SubDir>            
            <FilePath>C:\Test\a.txt</FilePath>
            <Date>18.Apr.13</Date>      
          </SubDir>          
        </Directory>
        <Directory>
        <InvokeBy>Script</InvokeBy>
        //below code have two SubDir Nodes having same file path, but it should consider any one and skip all remaining otherwise it will give incorrect count record. 
          <SubDir>            
            <FilePath>C:\Test\a.txt</FilePath>
            <Date>18.Apr.13</Date>      
          </SubDir> 
          <SubDir>
            <FilePath>C:\Test\a.txt</FilePath>
            <Date>18.Apr.13</Date>    
          </SubDir> 
        </Directory>
</Base>
```

Expected O/P for File2.xml

```
<table xmlns:w3="http://www.w3.org">
   <tr>
      <td>File</td>
      <td>Compared Status</td>
      <td>Registry</td>
      <td>Exe</td>
      <td>Script</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>C:\Test\a.txt</td> 
      <td>Equal</td>          //Here it should show Equal only when all invoke type have same file date, but it will be unequal if you consider code for count of maching occurrence.  by the code line.I have added at top
      <td>18.Apr.13</td>
      <td>18.Apr.13</td>
      <td>18.Apr.13</td>
   </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>C:\Test\b.txt</td>
      <td>UnEqual</td>
      <td>18.Apr.13</td>
      <td>NONE</td>
      <td>NONE</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please post (at least) an example XML input.

Comment: It would help very much if you could avoid abbreviations and be more careful with your writing. If you want others to spend time on your question, you should be ready to invest the time to type a few more letters and punctuation. Otherwise readers will waste more time to try and understand what the question actually is than how long it would take you to hit some extra keys.

Comment: Link I have given here Tim C explained that answer greatly, expected result I am looking for same as given link. but here comparison done by no of occurrence of matching record with no of stations present. code line I have pasted above. This comparison has no relation with value display in other columns, as it is not comparing result value it comparing no of matching record that exist in input (not in output). I have tried  this link code, Input xml similar to that link. Expected output will be compared result of value that are exist in column not the occurrence matching record from input file

Comment: *"if column1, column2, column3 has value "A" then status must be Equal"*  Where exactly are "column1, column2, column3" in the XML and what is value "A"?

Comment: In short count(key('networksAndIP', concat(w3:Name, '|', w3:IPAddress))) gives total no of occurrence it may be 10 or 5 depends on number of records but total stations are only 3 ($allStationsCount), so it will never shows correct result

Comment: I have updated my input file and output, please check output to understand my problem.

Comment: @Michael, Any suggestion/Hint?

Comment: Expecting suggestions...

Comment: I am afraid I still have no clue what this is about. Could you provide another example of input where the expected result is "Unequal"? P.S. Please be patient.

Comment: Is it possible  you are asking the same question as the one here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20739264/xslt-node-value-comparision/20820305?noredirect=1#comment31332691_20820305

Comment: @Michael, I am not asking question as per your suggested link. I have added another input file as per ur suggestion to understand my question. Hopeful to get help from you.

Comment: @Michael, I have added one more question, do you have any suggestion for it... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21825328/how-to-sort-result-column-as-it-is-not-part-of-xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works but its too slow...

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
     xmlns:w3="http://www.w3.org" exclude-result-prefixes="w3">

  <!-- grouping key to pull out all the DataNodeBase elements with a
       particular name -->
  <xsl:key name="dnbByName" match="w3:DataNodeBase" use="w3:Name" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="allStations"
                  select="/w3:OperatorStationCollection/w3:OperatorStation" />
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Name</td><td>Status</td>
        <xsl:for-each select="$allStations">
          <td><xsl:value-of select="w3:Name" /></td>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </tr>
      <!-- Muenchian grouping - for-each over a set consisting of just one
           DataNodeBase per network name "group" -->
      <xsl:for-each select="$allStations/w3:Nodes/w3:DataNodeBase[
            generate-id() = generate-id(key('dnbByName', w3:Name)[1])]">
        <xsl:variable name="current-group" select="key('dnbByName', w3:Name)" />
        <xsl:variable name="current-grouping-key" select="w3:Name" />
        <tr>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="$current-grouping-key" /></td>
          <td>
            <xsl:choose>
              <!-- "Equal" if all stations have a value for this network name,
                   and all these values are the same (it is not the case that
                   any of the values is different from that of the first
                   station) -->
              <xsl:when test="$current-group/w3:IPAddress = $current-group[1]/w3:IPAddress">
                <xsl:text>Equal</xsl:text>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:text>Unequal</xsl:text>
              </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
          </td>
          <!-- remaining columns, one per station -->
          <xsl:for-each select="$allStations">
            <td>
              <!-- check whether this station has an address for this network -->
              <xsl:variable name="address" select="w3:Nodes/w3:DataNodeBase[
                      w3:Name = $current-grouping-key]/w3:IPAddress" />
              <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$address">
                  <xsl:value-of select="$address" />
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>None</xsl:otherwise>
              </xsl:choose>
            </td>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```